# FFMPEG documentation example for chromakey doesn't work for green background png file

Tags: ffmpeg

Im new in FFMPEG and I try to make just simple green background chroma keying of png images.
In FFMPEG documentation in 38.16 Chromakey - there is an example script:

ffmpeg -i input.png -vf chromakey=green out.png

for which is said that "Make every green pixel in the input image transparent"
That exactly what i wanted.
I tried with many different png images but the result is always a copy of input image.
Also i replaced the word "green" to 0x00FF00 or 0x008000 and still no successes. Only when replacing green to black and then the result is as expected - transparent.
Im working on Windows with  pre-build binaries of FFMpeg.
What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Provide a link to `input.png`.

Answer (score 0):

When working with RGB pixel formats (like in PNG), use the colorkey filter. Also, specify colour as hex codes, since ffmpeg's colour labels may not match what you expect e.g. Green is `0x008000`, and not `0x00FF00`.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vf colorkey=0x00FF00 out.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vf colorkey=0x008000 out.png
```

works.
I also found / after so much reading other related information/ that "chromakey" CAN work as well. Here is how

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vf "chromakey=0x008000:0.1:0.1" -c copy -c:v png out.png
```

this work fine as well - the reason is codec -c:v of png.

A little bit more info- when i compared the results from @Gyan method and the second method - the second method produce much more anti aliased result.